# django- 404 message but no runserver error

Tags: python, django, database, server

I'm working on this django tutorial docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/ and I'm having a hard time getting my server to run, so that I can view and edit it on a website interface:

This is what is supposed to come up when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

[image: supposed]

But instead I get a 404 error message.  This is what happens when I run Python manage.py runserver

[image: error]

> Error: That port is already in use.

there aren't really any Errors it just says the port is already in use, I think that's because I ran that line of code twice.

I'm not entirely sure exactly what files i'll need to change to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your server python process is hang. Close your console, open it again and try to rerun your server.

If after trying that you are still getting `port already in use` message. Try to kill the process by yourself.

```
ps aux | grep -i manage
```

You will get something like this

```
14770     8264  0.0  1.9 546948 40904 ?        S    Sep19   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then kill it using `kill -9 pid`

```
kill -9 8264
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some extra info

If 8000 port is already in use, you can use other ports to run your Python-Django server by specifying the port like `python manage.py runserver 9000` as Django uses the 8000 port by **default** if you don't specify any.

Though your original problem must have been resolved by the solution @levi provided.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you typed CTRL + Z (probably by mistake), which suspends the foreground process. Use `fg` to bring the dev server process back to the foreground again.

See: https://superuser.com/q/476873/596978).